# Proof that $1$ divides $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I'm trying to prove that $1\mid n$ for $1, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

\begin{align}1 \mid n&\Leftrightarrow 1 \cdot x = n\\&\Leftrightarrow x = n,\end{align} where $n,x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Is this correct?

Comment: i think you should emphasize "there exists an $x$"

Comment: Your proof needs sentences. Not just a flurry of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct, because you write $1\cdot x=n$ without saying what $x$ is. The idea is good, though.

A correct proof would be: $1\mid n$ because $1\times n=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, kind of. I would go like $1|n \iff \exists x : 1x=n$. But then $x = n$ gives you $1x=1n=n \implies 1|n$.

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of the *divisibility* is the following:

$$a\mid b\iff \exists k\in \mathbb Z,\quad b=ak.$$

So in your proof, $x$ is not well quantified.

You just need to show that *there exists* some $x$ that satisfies $1\cdot x=n$.

You are right when you say that $x=n$ works.

So indeed, $1\mid n$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use quantifiers and/or words to make the proof more precise and easier to follow.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $1\cdot n = n$. Hence, by definition, $1\ \vert\ n$. As $n$ was arbitrary, it follows that $1\ \vert\ n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.